# Why does my URL template tag err?

Tags: django

I am trying to retrieve the URL of a view in a template via

```
{% url 'session_views.login_user' %}
```

My urls.py looks like

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myappname',

  # Greets user on the home page.
  (r'^$', 'session_views.index'),

  # Session
  (r'^login/?$', 'session_views.login_user'),
)
```

However, I get the following error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering:
Reverse for ''session_views.login_user'' with arguments '()'
and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Why am I erring? I clearly defined a view called `login_user` in session_views.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error `Reverse for ''session_views.login_user''`, it has two sets of single quotes. You do not use the quotes in the template - it should read:

`{% url session_views.login_user %}`

Or you can name your views - after which you would be able to call them via the name, and it would need the quotes:

urls.py:

> urlpatterns = patterns('myappname',
>
> # Greets user on the home page.   (r'^$', 'session_views.index', name="index_view"),
>
> # Session   (r'^login/?$', 'session_views.login_user', name="login_user"), )

template url reverse:

`{% url "login_user" %}`

EDIT:

After seeing `Tomita's` answer, I may have misunderstood the question. I thought you were trying to retrieve the URL as in follow it, and you may be trying to retrieve the url as a variable. My answer applies to following the URL, as in `<a href="{% url session_views.login_user %}"....`. Just in case, I will leave it.

Comment: +1, no your answer is correct. I was supplementing your answer with another option. He can fix it by going to <1.5 syntax, or fix it by loading 1.5 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking at the dev branch documentation, which changes the URL tag functionality.

For django <1.5, you should either follow the appropriate docs, or future proof your code by loading the future url tag.

```
{% load url from future %}
```

> In Django 1.5, the behavior of the url template tag will change, with
>   the first argument being made into a context variable, rather than
>   being a special case unquoted constant. This will allow the url tag to
>   use a context variable as the value of the URL name to be reversed.
>
> In order to provide a forwards compatibility path, Django 1.3 provides
>   a future compatibility library -- future -- that implements the new
>   behavior. To use this library, add a load call at the top of any
>   template using the url tag, and wrap the first argument to the url tag
>   in quotes. For example:
>
> {% load url from future %} {% url 'myapp:view-name' %} The new library
>   also drops support for the comma syntax for separating arguments to
>   the url template tag.
>
> In Django 1.5, the old behavior will be replaced with the behavior
>   provided by the future tag library. Existing templates be migrated to
>   use the new syntax.